# Jqgrid loadtext not centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid

I customized jqgrid loadtext to a longer string than the default "loading",
but can't get the text to center:

loadtext: `'this is my loading text'`,

the rendered html is:

```
<div id="xxx" 
     class="loading ui-state-default ui-state-active" 
     style="display: none;">this is my loading text</div>
```

I can put whatever html into loadtext, however, it still would not center.  is there a way?

Comment: style="display: none; text-align:center;" doesnt work? how big is the div? is it in antoher div?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was override jqGrid's css like so:

```
.ui-jqgrid .loading 
{
    background-image: url(jqgrid-loading.gif);
    border-style: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
```

I used an image but you can do the same thing with text.

The loading image is now centered vertically and horizontally